# How select any node except p in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I want to select any `node` except `<p>` in XSLT and show its value inside `rap` element. I tried the below code for that.

Input:

```
<section>
  <rap>
    <bold>Device,</bold>
    <p><bold>manufacturer,</bold></p>
    This is paragaraph without element
    <p><bold>country</bold></p>
    <p><bold>country2</bold></p>
  </rap>
</section>
```

Tried code:

```
<xsl:template match="rap[p]/node()[. except p]">
    <rap>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </rap>
</xsl:template>
```

Expected output:

```
<output>
  <rap>Device,</rap>
  <rap>This is paragaraph without element</rap>
</rap>
```

Current output:

```
<output><rap>
            </rap></output><output><rap>Device,</rap></output><output><rap>
            </rap></output><output><rap>manufacturer,</rap></output><output><rap>
            This is paragaraph without element
            </rap></output><output><rap>country</rap></output><output><rap>
            </rap></output><output><rap>country2</rap></output><output><rap>
        </rap></output>
```

Tried xsltfiddle: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNvtBGs/2

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<xsl:template match="rap">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="node()[normalize-space() ne '']">
        <xsl:if test="not(self::p)">
            <rap><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></rap>
        </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>
```

See Transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNvtBGs/3

Answer (score 0):

I think I would rather use the `except` operator in the `select` of the `apply-templates`:

```
<xsl:template match="section">
    <output>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rap[p]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() except p"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rap/node()[normalize-space()]">
    <rap><xsl:value-of select="."/></rap>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNvtBGs/4